# Testing an XS module that uses Dist::Zilla

Tags: perl, testing, xs, dist-zilla

I'm working on a Perl module that has a lot of XS code and also uses `Dist::Zilla` to manage packaging.  What's the best way to test things efficiently?  I know about `dzil test`, but that's pretty slow because it does a full build/compile/test cycle every time it's invoked.

It would be nice to only update the parts that need updating since last test, and also to be able to run only certain `t/*.t` test scripts rather than all of them.  Anyone have a solution that they like?

Comment: ha ha ha =)  Yeah, in particular it would be nice to quicken the code/test cycle for the MongoDB package.

Answer (score 2):

I have, in the past, just taken a Build.PL/Makefile.PL as generated by dzil and dropped it into the source repository as a "Makefile_dev.PL" (or "Build_dev.PL"), added it to MANIFEST.SKIP (or the dzil-based, generated equivalent) and used it during development.

Answer (score 1):

For my XS modules, I use either [MakeMaker::Custom](https://metacpan.org/module/Dist%3a%3aZilla%3a%3aPlugin%3a%3aMakeMaker%3a%3aCustom) or [ModuleBuild::Custom](https://metacpan.org/module/Dist%3a%3aZilla%3a%3aPlugin%3a%3aModuleBuild%3a%3aCustom) (both by me).  If you set things up properly, you can run Makefile.PL or Build.PL directly in your repo without invoking `dzil` at all.  To run specific tests, you just build the dist and use `prove -b testname`.

Some examples using ModuleBuild::Custom: [Media-LibMTP-API](https://github.com/madsen/media-libmtp-api), [Win32-IPC](https://github.com/madsen/win32-ipc).

An example using MakeMaker::Custom: [Win32-Setupsup](https://github.com/madsen/win32-setupsup).

Answer (score 1):

I know I'm pigeonholing myself as old-school, but its for these very reasons that I don't use Dist::Zilla: when it works its great, when it doesn't it can be really hard to make it do what you want.

I guess that means, my answer is: when it gets too hard, just move to one of the primary tools that dzil generates, ie. EUMM or MB directly.

Comment: Yeah, I hear you.  Still not going to give it up though. =)  It just surprises me there's no ready-built solution to the testing thing though.